# Read file with weird windows path using python

Tags: python, windows, filepath, filenotfoundexception, os.walk

With Python 3

I have an external drive with a Dropbox backup. I have been copying files from this drive to another location using python by using `os.walk` and iterating thru the files. `os.walk` will produce a valid folder and file name.

ie `W:\Z Drive Backup 4-14-18\Dropbox\Autodesk 2018 Win\file.xyz`

However, when using `open` or `os.stat`, it give me a `FileNotFoundError`.

`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'W:/Z Drive Backup 4-14-18/Dropbox/Autodesk 2018 Win`

Opening the file properties it shows the location with `\\?\` in front of it. See photo. If I add this to the file path, I still get the same error.

I ran into a lot of folder and files while doing this that had funky Unicode or other characters in the path. I was able to identify these and replace the bad character with `str.replace` for most of them. I think this issue with `\\?\` up front is the same type of issue, however, it can't even see the file in python for me to rename it.

Any ideas how to fix the file path?

If I rename the file on that drive it does not fix the problem. If I copy the file to another location, then it is fine. But has the problem when copying back. There are a lot of files, so I don't want to do any of it manually.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have either an extra or a missing quote somewhere...

Comment: You probably should remove personal info from your screen shot

Comment: By default, Windows path normalization emulates MS-DOS rules, such as limiting paths to `MAX_PATH` (260) characters; translating forward slashes to backslash; reserving DOS device names such as "CON" and "NUL"; and stripping trailing spaces and dots from the final filename component. The "\\?\" path prefix instructs Windows to bypass this normalization step. It should be used only with a fully-qualified path that's UTF-16 Unicode (Python 3 `str`, but Python 3.6+ file-system functions implicitly decode UTF-8 bytes paths to UTF-16) and uses only backslash as the path separator.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Windows 10, version 1607, MAX_PATH limitations have been removed from common Win32 file and directory functions. However, you must opt-in to the new behavior

To Opt In, edit the registry key
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem@LongPathsEnabled to 1

References:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
https://bugs.python.org/issue27731